# How can I re-formating PHP code, returning duplicate attribute class?

Tags: php, class

Dears, I would like ask you for help with formating PHP code.
Because W3C validator, return me this as error, "*Error: Duplicate attribute class.*"
I have now next PHP code:

```
$html .= '<a href="'.$href.'"';
if($this->hasChilds($item, $nazev)) $html .= ' class="qmparent"';
if ((empty($view) && $item->view == 'main') || (empty($display) && $view == $item->view) || (!empty($display) && $display == $item->display)) $html .= ' class="active"';
$html .= '>';
```

This giving me html 
code: `<a href="link.html" class="qmparent" class="active">LINK</a>`
And I would like, can will be generate,
a different html 
code: `<a href="link.html" class="qmparent active" >LINK</a>`

Can I ask you for help, how to rewrite? I donť know if it is enough for correct sense, if not I will add much of code. Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

The error is HTML error because you have duplicated class. In HTML it is ok to have empty class attribute. So you can append classes then add them to the HTML class attribute. See the code:

```
$classes = '';
if($this->hasChilds($item, $nazev)) $classes .= ' qmparent';
if ((empty($view) && $item->view == 'main') || (empty($display) && $view == $item->view) || (!empty($display) && $display == $item->display)) $classes .= ' active';
$html .= '<a href="'.$href.'"class ="'.$classes.'"/>';
```

To have better structure, it is common to separate the view from model. So you can create a data array that contains or your HTML elements with final classes, type and id. Then pass this array to view to construct the view correctly.

Comment: Thanks so much for your advice, it works great!
I guess I was completely blind or sleepless' :-)
This is a very old project, I just went through it and wanted to have everything valid.
I needed to kick me right.
Thanks again, have a good time.

Comment: @user3452734 Your welcome, if the answer did solve the issue you could marked as accepted.

Comment: I would like send "accepted" but, I'm sorry, I didnt find how to, even if I did read help.